# objective c iphone : can we view console log on device

Tags: iphone, console, device

is there a way to view the console output as we are running an iphone App on the device?
If not directly, is there an app on the App store which lets you view the log after the App has finished running?

Comment: According to the developer's blog he used asl functions to access the logs, here http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html

Comment: As of iOS 7.0, the app sandbox now prohibits access to any logs that aren't the app's: [via this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19045750/774) (also observed personally when using on-device apps to view the device's logs)

Answer (score 21):

Update to use Xcode 12.5.1 and Console 1.1:

In Xcode go to Window->Devices and Simulators, select your device and press on "Open Console" button.

Or directly open Console by pressing cmd+space -> type "Console" and press enter.

In the Console app select your device from left pane and press on "Start streaming".

[image]

---

You can also see in Devices window.

Go in xcode -> Window -> Devices.

Select your device and open the console.[image]

Comment: **-1 Does not answer the question.** OP is asking to view the console's contents _on-device_; this answer uses a development computer with Xcode.

Comment: Where is this in Xcode 6?

Comment: in Xcode 6 -> Window -> Devices -> Select the device -> a little arrow /\ at the bottom left,
Click this and it will pop open the device console.

Comment: Get [iSyslog][1].

Works also on iOS7 and iOS8. Runs natively on any device (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad). No jailbreaking required. 

  [1]: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isyslog-system-monitoring/id468155763?mt=8

Comment: @KarolyNyisztor iSyslog doesn't appear to be available currently.

Comment: @ThomasW Yeah, it took a while, but Apple eventually closed the security loophole that allowed the app to access the system logs.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log",[NSDate date]];

NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

Just add this block of code in `applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions` method in app delegate file, and it will create a log file in app Document Directory on iphone which logs all console log events. You need to import this file from itunes to see all console events.

Dont Forget to   set "Application supports iTunes file sharing"  to "YES" in Your plist

Goto - itunes -when ur device connected-Apps - select ur App - in Augument Document u will get ur file then save to ur disk

Comment: thanks, but I am unable to find the app document directory, can you please help me to find that .log file to import from iTunes

Comment: Seems with iTunes 12 we can't import files from the document directory anymore. Now everything is iCloud. How can users get this log file?

Comment: Works fine for me with Xcode 7.3 and iTunes 12.3.3.17

Answer (score 2):

if you have a paid iphone developer account, you can use the organizer window in xcode to view the console and app logs on your devices.

Comment: oh no thats not the issue ... I am developing a Location Based application, for which I need to run with my iphone. Its a little cumbersome to run with my macbook in one hand and iphone in the other. Any "on device log viewer"?

Comment: you could make your app NSLog the data you want to see and view it later using the organizer. i think there's no way to see it live on-device unless you add you own ui to print it out.

Comment: **-1 Does not answer the question** OP is asking to view the console's contents _on-device_; this approach uses a development computer with Xcode.