# Reading & sending crash logs to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

On the fly can I read & send the crash logs generated from my previous crash. Which folder should I read? And I want to delete the logs once sent so that for next crash I do not end up sending previous crash logs. I will be sending the logs to server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using QuincyKit to collect and send crash logs: https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit

The framework comes with a server side backend, but if you don't want to run your own server you can also use [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/). As far as I know [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) is also planning to offer a similar service.

If you implement your own solution, you probably shouldn't delete the crash logs on the device, but remember the date of the last crash log sent to your server.

Comment: I had no idea this was possible.  This is my one thing learned today!  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can access the system logs on iOS using the ASL (Apple System Logger) APIs, previously [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144347/using-objective-c-to-read-log-messages-posted-to-the-device-console)

There's a free app in the store that does this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634929/objective-c-iphone-can-we-view-console-log-on-device/2840773#2840773).  I find this is useful to see the logs when you're not connected to Xcode.