# Where are iPhone files stored?

Tags: ios, iphone

Apps like iFunbox,iExplorer can access apps from your iPhone when it is plugged in. Does anyone know where the files are kept when you plug in your phone. I'm on a Mac by the way.

I'm not talking about backups though, in case you were wondering. ;)

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: I'm writing a program though... and I didn't know where I could find my phone's files.

Comment: The fact that you are wiring a program is irrelevant to the question. Your question has nothing to do with programming. It's asking about how some other software works.

Comment: `Does anyone know where the files are kept when you plug in your phone` still on your phone, no? Please clarify your question. Honestly, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: What I'm asking is how do I access the files on my phone from my computer WITHOUT backup.

Comment: By using iFunBox and iExplorer which are accessing phone's filesystem directly. If that is not what you're asking then I don't know.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980545/command-line-access-to-ios-app-directory-sandbox-from-mac

Answer (score 1):

Native applications are stored in ar/db/stash/"randomly_generated_code"/Applications . While third-party apps are stored in /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Applications , although this is strictly on iOS 9. On iOS 8 Third party applications were stored in the stash as well.

Comment: I meant "Where are they stored" on my mac.

Comment: Apps that are synchronised to/from your phone are stored in the iTunes library. Simply plugging in a phone doesn't transfer the apps to your Mac; you have to sync or backup.

Comment: Wrong on both cases. `Stash` is a directory made by Cydia when you first launch it. It moves system applications to user partition (`/var/stash` or `/var/db/stach`) leaving only the symlink on the system one. That's because the system partition is very small so you can't install many Cydia applications onto it. Without jailbreak system apps are still on the system partition at `/Applications`. `/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Applications` is used on both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Comment: Ok, thanks that help, @creker. In that case is there any way I could access my phone's files from my Mac without backup, if not, I will remove thread, and apologize for the inconvienice

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't know that. I have only searched for the folders whilst I was jailbroken

Answer (score -1):

iPhone Backup Location for Mac OS X

In Mac OS X your iPhone files are backed up at the following location:

~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/

The (~) symbol signifies your home directory, which is at the same place where all your other personal documents are stored.

iPhone Backup Location for Windows 8, 7, XP, and Vista

Windows XP stores all of your iPhone backup files in this location:

C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup

Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 back up the iPhone files here:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup

Obviously if your main drive is not C: then you’ll have to change that, same goes for ‘user’

Note to Windows users: the Application Data and AppData directories and their contents (iPhone backups included) are considered ‘hidden’ so you will need to enable ‘Show hidden files’ within Windows Explorer before you will be able to see the files.

Source: http://www.iphonebackup-extractor.com/faqs.html#iphone-backup-location

Comment: I said I wasn't talking about backups.