# I can't get WatchConnectivity's session:didRecieveMessage: to be called

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I've tried to get WatchConnectivity to work, but I can't send (location) messages from my iPhone to my Apple Watch.
In AppDelegate I set up the session:

```
var session: WCSession!    

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
    return true
}
```

In my ViewController:

```
let manager = CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.manager.delegate = self
    // CLLocationManager status handling code
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { // I know this is called
    if let locationData = manager.location {
        let location = ["location" : locationData]
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).session.sendMessage(locationData, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Here the relevant Interface Controller code:

```
var session: WCSession!

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}


func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) { // This method is never called
    let location = message["location"] as? CLLocation
    print(location)
}
```

However, my InterfaceController does not receive the message, nothing is printed, and the breakpoint I put is not triggered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the dictionary passed to sendMessage can only contain property list types (basics such as numbers, strings, data, etc). I bet if you added an error handler you'd get an error indicating the payload cannot be sent because it contains invalid (non plist) types

Also, when you call sendMessage if you pass in a nil replyHandler a different delegate method is called on the receiving side than if there is a replyHandler. Try implementing the other delegate didReceiveMessage method:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])
```

Comment: I tries passing a `CLLocationDistance`, it's still not working even though it's a `typealias Double`

Comment: @ILikeTau are you using the latest seed? Is your error handler being invoked with an error?

Comment: No, I'm getting problems with passing a `String` into `print()`. It fails to compile.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a theory of what is going wrong

Comment: I've got it to compile, waiting for it to run on my watch

Comment: Works in the simulator, doesn't on my watch. I can't debug either.

Comment: Any errors being returned to the errorHandler on the sending side? Are you running seed 4 or 5 on your devices?

Comment: iOS PB 3; watchOS DP 5. I cannot debug; thus nothing prints, breakpoints don't work, etc.

Comment: You should be able to see the logs in Xcode even if you cannot debug (see here for details to see a device's console log: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28582642/386521)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87122/discussion-between-iliketau-and-ccjensen).