# Get iOS app logs by command line

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, automation, itunes-sdk

is there a possibility to get the app logs (not crash reports) from iOS devices by a command line tool?

The goal is to provide an automation to get the logs from the device.

Greets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277804/ios-iphone-ipad-ipodtouch-view-real-time-console-log-terminal ?