# How do I access my data in a PKPushPayload?

Tags: pushkit, node-apn

XCode 7, Swift 2. (don't even start on me about that, it's not my favorite set of constraints either)

So I'm sending data using [node-apn](https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn) (BIG thanks to those folks!). I'm using the (pushkit option) `*.voip` topic and I got all that working. I can see the notification is received on my device (big shout out to [libimobiledevice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148654/1449799)).

In composing the note on my server i'm doing

```
var note = new apn.Notification();
note.topic = 'mine.voip';
note.payload = {
    message: 'text',
    somethingElse: 'this other one '
    payload: {
        k1: v1,
        k2: {
          k3: v2
        }        
    }
};
```

How am I supposed to get at my payload object? Following some (3rd party) pushkit examples (maybe it was [1](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/)? that showed like

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    let payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
    let message = payloadDict?["alert"]
}
```

I tried to mimic it like

```
let myWeirdPayload = payload.dictionaryPayload["payload"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
```

or even

```
let myWeirdPayload = payload.dictionaryPayload["payload"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
```

but those don't work (I get `nil`).

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: For some reason using NSDictionary works for me, but I don't know why that should be necessary?
    if let myPayload = payloadDict["payload"] as? NSDictionary { ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I log it in Obj-C:

```m
NSLog(@"pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:withCompletionHandler:%@", 
      payload.dictionaryPayload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to make this clear by explaining the relation between `PKPushPayload` and its `NSDictionary` property with the data you are looking for.

For the `func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!)` you have the `payload` argument which is a `PKPushPayload`.

The data you are looking for are stored in the `_dictionaryPayload` which is a `NSDictionary` and it is a property of the `payload` argument.

So to access the data you can do:

```
let payloadDictionary = payload.dictionaryPayload as NSDictionary
let myData = payloadDictionary.value(forKey: "myData_unique_key")
```