# Display console for log statements within app for third-party debugging in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, ios7

I'm trying to implement a debug page within my iOS app for third-party debugging. Ideally, this page would display all of my app's log output similar to what you would see in Xcode's console.

Has anyone implemented this? Third party apps used to exist to show complete console output, but it appears that they are no longer practical in iOS 7. It is my understanding that system wide log statements, as well as log statements from external apps are inaccessible as of iOS 7 due to a stricter sandboxing policy.

References:

[objective c iphone : can we view console log on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634929/objective-c-iphone-can-we-view-console-log-on-device)

[Display console for log statements within app for third-party debugging in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203599/display-console-for-log-statements-within-app-for-third-party-debugging-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LSLogViewer](https://github.com/fins/LSLogViewer) library. It shows a debug window with console logs (NSLog) from your application. It also allows to send those logs to your email address.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about statements you could log with `NSLog()`? If so, you could create a wrapper class that logs/appends the data to a file, and then have a notification post whenever that gets updated in order to update the UI (in the event you wanted to show logs in real time).

As far as OS messages go, I'm not sure there's a way to log those.